# null pointer exception in below code

Tags: java

In below code last sop is not printed having

```
String A=null;

if (A.contains("xyz")) {
    System.out.println("loop1");
}
System.out.println(A);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since A is null above code will throw a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)(NPE) which is a RuntimeException.

The exception will be thrown when any invocation is performed on null, in your case a contains method call.

```
A.contains("xyz")
```

Comment: See my comments on @Nambari's answer about your last statement.

Comment: @All : Actually above Snippet is in for loop and for one time it is having null value, rest of the time it is having values so how to fix this so that null one get avoided and others get accepted ?

Comment: @adityasingh you need to perform a null check before you invoke a method on A. That should look like A != null && A.contains("xyz")

Answer (score 4):

A is `null`, and you are calling `if (A.contains("xyz"))`

Any invocation on `null` reference results `NullPointerException`, you don't have above statement wrapped in try/catch, so exception propagates to higher level without executing code further below.

Change it to something like:

```
String A="";
```

Comment: Not any `operation` on `null` throws `NPE`. `"xyd".equals(null)` for eg runs fine. You should say, `any invocation` on null throws `NPE`.

Comment: @RohitJain: Ok, changed wording.

Comment: @RohitJain: Do we call equals operation on xyd (or) null in above syntax? Not an expert in English. I usually think, object left and then .(dot) and operation on that object isn't it?

Comment: @Nambari.. Yeah. You're right. That's how it is. We invoke `equals` method on "xyd".

Comment: @RohitJain: Ok, then your comment may not stand.

Comment: @Nambari.. Well, I think my 1st example doesn't very well prove my point. Let's take another example: - `"abc" + null` or `null + "abc"` is an operation on `null` right? But that doesn't throw `NPE`. It will take `null` as a string, and do the concatenation. That's why it should be `invocation` and not `operation`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (A.contains("xyz")) {
```

As A is null, you are trying to call Contains on A. Thus NPE

Comment: Actually, it probably happens at `if (A.contains("xyz"))`

Answer (score 0):

In `String A=null;` you are setting the String reference A to null. At this point you have a reference, but it is not pointing to an object yet. Then you try to use the reference as if it was pointing to an object by calling the `.contains` method, which will result in a NullPointerException since there is no code to execute in the location that the reference is pointing.